# Подсчет количества голов. SQL запрос

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица, где хранятся результативные действия игроков. Есть поле, которые под определенным индексом хранит определенное действие(1-гол, 2-пас) и поле id игрока. Как подсчитать количество голов каждого игрока.

Comment: выбрать строки с нужным действием, взять игрока, подсчитать число строк, сгруппировать по игрокам

Comment: А как именно мне выбрать строки с нужным действием? Через инструкцию if?

Comment: с помощью `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы проще конечно видя структуру базы.

```
CREATE TABLE `gol` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `event_enum` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `gol` (`id`, `user_id`, `event_enum`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 1, 1),
    (4, 2, 1),
    (5, 3, 2);
```

Если правильно понял, и вам посчитать только количество голов. То так

```
SELECT
    g.user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS golCount
FROM gol g
WHERE g.event_enum = 1
GROUP BY g.user_id
```

Если конкретно каждого типа событий то можно

```
SELECT
    g.user_id,
    g.event_enum,
    COUNT(*) AS countEvent
FROM gol g
GROUP BY g.user_id, event_enum
```

Либо

```
SELECT
    g.user_id,
    COUNT(IF (event_enum = 1, 1, NULL)) AS golCounter,
    COUNT(IF (event_enum = 2, 1, NULL)) AS pasCounter
FROM gol g
GROUP BY g.user_id
```

Comment: Уже сделал, спасибо.